# How to force reformat whole file in PhpStorm using all declared rules?

Tags: phpstorm, reformat, reformatting

How can I force PhpStorm to reformat code but "from the scratch". Question seems to be dumb, but I noticed that if I for example make some changes manually, it will keep that changes even if that change breaks rules that was set.

Example:

I have Object creation with constructor arguments (reformatted):
[image: My source code]

But if I paste it to File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->PHP editor it will reformat it just like that:
[image: Reformatted code in File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->PHP]

Where is the difference coming from? Why reformat tool is ignoring it's own rules? How can I force it to reformat it properly?

Comment: Have you tried this: 1) Select whole file content and then hit Reformat shortcut? 2) or select the file in Project View panel and hit Reformat from there (this way it can be invoked on multiple files/folders). 3) Other than that -- `Code | Show Reformat File Dialog` and see if it has some unwanted option selected (e.g. "Only VCS changed text")

Comment: Yeah, i have tried it :/ I have got "Whole File" and "Optimize Import" options enabled, so it should work in this case in my opinion.

Comment: Try "resetting" your code style rules then. First -- just try Default one -- just to see if your code fragment in question gets reformatted at all. Then create new code style entry (scheme) from Default; apply desired styles (at very least for the elements in question) and try using it -- minimal changes just to see if it will work at all as required. If all good -- finish setting up other rules.

Comment: This probably has to do with your right margin. In the example view it's probably much smaller than in your actual project files.

From your screenshots I assume you always want one array item per line, if the declaration is being wrapped. To do so, set "array initialiser" to 'Chop down if long', rather than 'Wrap if long'.

Also, make sure the code style profile you are setting things up for is the one you are actually using when reformatting code.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings window example, the right margin is probably much smaller than in your actual project. The right margin for your project can be set in your generic code style settings.

---

If you go to *File* -> *Settings* -> *Editor* -> *Code Style* -> *PHP* -> *Wrapping and Braces*, you have four options for 'Array intializer':

[image: PhpStorm code style settings]

- **Do not wrap**: will not change your own formatting.
- **Wrap if long**: will wrap the array elements if the line gets too long, but might still keep multiple array items together on one line if that fits within the margins.
- **Chop down if long**: will wrap the array items if the line gets too long. If items are being wrapped, every item is places on its own line.
- **Wrap always**: always puts each array element on its own line, even if the original line was not long enough.

---

You probably have it set to *wrap if long* now. That means it does get wrapped, but several array items might still end up together on the same line. As long as it fits on the line, it complies with the code style.

You probably want to set it to *chop down if long*, meaning that if things get wrapped, you will always have one item per line.

Comment: Thank You for the answer :) I set it, maybe it will do the job. Have You any idea whether it is possible to force apply formatting rules ?

Comment: What do you mean by force applying? Any formatting rule will be applied as soon as you format the code, if that's what you mean.